# Has Android Camera2 Api Bayer mipi 10rggb raw image format support?

Tags: android, android-camera2, raw

I am working on camera2 api update for my project where I used the camera library before. While using the camera library, I can take images in Jpeg and Raw (Bayer mipi 10rggb) formats, but currently I can only get images in Jpeg format. When I look at the output formats from the camera's map `characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId); StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);`, I can't see any value in the raw image format. And also i search for all image formats at ImageFormat class but i can not see the Bayer Mipi 10RGGB image format. Regardless of that, when I load the raw10 (which is also 10 bits raw format) format into the imageReader, I get a null pointer error. However, in the old camera code, when I set the camera parameters directly in Bayer Mipi 10 RGGB format, I could get output in this format.

```
parameters.set("picture-format", CameraController.RAW_FORMAT); 
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

I really have no idea what to do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the device does not list the [RAW capability](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_RAW), then you cannot rely on it supporting the [RAW_SENSOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/ImageFormat#RAW_SENSOR:kotlin.Int) format.

I'm not sure where you're getting the value of `CameraController.RAW_FORMAT` from, but there's no public definition of a raw Bayer format for the deprecated camera1 API; so you're using a custom extension value. It might work for some devices, but there's no real guarantees on which ones.

So it seems like your test device might unofficially support a RAW format via the old API, but it doesn't support the public camera2 RAW_SENSOR format and metadata needed to interpret it.

Comment: The CameraController.RAW_FORMAT value is "bayer-mipi-10rggb". I forgot to specify it. Thank you for reply. I guess I will go on with camera api1.